# Sorting points total in descending order in knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js

I'm trying to sort teams' points in descending order and I'm not understanding why my sort isn't working?

https://jsfiddle.net/cjm2o08n/4/

```
<!-- ko foreach: teams -->
<span data-bind="text: name"></span> <span data-bind="text: points"></span>
<br/>
<!-- /ko -->




function Point(label, value) {
  var self = this;
  self.label = ko.observable(label);
  self.value = ko.observable(value);
}

function Team(name) {
  var self = this;
  self.name = ko.observable(name);
  self.rank = ko.observable(0);
  self.points = ko.observable(0);
}

function AppViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.teams = ko.observableArray([
    new Team('red'),
    new Team('blue'),
    new Team('yellow'),
    new Team('green'),
  ]);
  self.points = ko.observableArray([
    new Point('1st', 20),
    new Point('2nd', 10),
    new Point('3rd', 5)
  ]);

  self.tester = function() {
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.teams(), function(team) {
      //get team ranking and then find it in points
      team.points(
        self.points()[team.rank() - 1].value()
      )
    });
    //sort by highest points
    self.teams(
      self.teams().sort(function(left, right) {
        return left.points == right.points ? 0 : (left.points < right.points ? 1 : -1)
      })
    );
  };
}

var vm = new AppViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);

vm.teams()[0].rank(2);
vm.teams()[1].rank(1);
vm.teams()[2].rank(3);
vm.teams()[3].rank(4);

vm.tester();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three things:

1. You're missing fourth place, making your application *crash* inside the `arrayForEach` when finding the `points` for `teams()[4]`. *Be sure to check the console for errors before posting questions online* ;-)
2. You're comparing *observables*, not their values. You need to invoke `left.points` and `right.points` to get their value.
3. An `observableArray` conveniently has the `sort` function itself, which will sort the underlying array;

In short, you need to change your `points` to this:

```
self.points = ko.observableArray([
    new Point('1st', 20),
    new Point('2nd', 10),
    new Point('3rd', 5),
    new Point('4th', 0)
]);
```

And your `tester` to this:

```
self.tester = function() {
  ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.teams(), function(team) {
    //get team ranking and then find it in points
    team.points(
      self.points()[team.rank() - 1].value()
    )
  });
  //sort by highest points
  self.teams.sort(function(left, right) {
    return left.points() == right.points() ? 0 : (left.points() < right.points() ? 1 : -1)
  });
};
```

By the way, you can simplify your sort even to this:

```
  self.teams.sort(function(left, right) {
    return right.points() - left.points();
  });
```

And [things will work as intended](https://jsfiddle.net/9Lmtbsb4/).

Answer (score 2):

Sort isn't working for these 2 errors.

**1st is this code:**

```
self.points()[team.rank() - 1].value()
```

points observable array only contains 3 values while team rank can have the value of 4 so `self.points()[3].value()` will produce an error.

Fix would be to add another value in points array like : `new Point('4th', 0)` or you can find another way like trapping if the index is out of bounds.

**2nd is this part (sorting):**

```
return left.points == right.points ? 0 : (left.points < right.points ? 1 : -1)
```

Remember that points is an observable so you need to call it as a function

```
return left.points() == right.points() ? 0 : (left.points() < right.points() ? 1 : -1)
```

or you can even sort it using the rank you have provided

```
return left.rank() - right.rank()
```

Here is a modified fiddle that you have provided.
https://jsfiddle.net/56jgehjw/

Comment: Your last suggestion [will not work](https://jsfiddle.net/54v4y4d1/) unless you switch the `<` around (though in general I'd recommend not returning true/false from the comparison function at all, but a number instead; better return e.g. `right.rank() - left.rank()`).

Comment: Oh yeah, i haven't checked that comparison, that one will provide ascending order :D provided an edit already.